# Best way to select 2 tables mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select

PHP + MYSQL

I have 2 tables:

- "post" columns: [id, comment]
- "images" columns: [id, post, image]

I need to show in my html page the posts, with the images in each post. Example:

---

My first post comment (this post has one image)

- image 1

---

My second post comment (this post has three images)

- image 1
- image 2
- image 3

---

My third post (this post has two images)

- image 1
- image 2

...

One way to do it is: for each post, go to database and get the images... but I think that as less access to database is better... how can I do my select?

( I would like ONE line per POST... ) is it possible?

Result example:

COLUMN POST - COLUMN IMAGE

"My first post" - "image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg"

Is there another better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: is the post column on images the referenced id from the post table?

Comment: sounds like you just need a JOIN in your querry

Comment: yes @Prix... is a foreign key...

Comment: Returning separate rows for `images` would be a more "portable" approach, the same design can be used with different databases. Returning the individual images values in a column relies on  together in a single vendor specific extensions, MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT`, Oracle 11gR2 `LISTAGG`, SQL Server `STUFF(subquery)`, etc.

Comment: Yes, true story @spencer7593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate multiple images related to one post, as in the following example :

```
SELECT POST.ID AS POST_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(IMAGES.IMAGE) AS IMAGES
FROM POST
JOIN IMAGES ON IMAGES.POST = POST.ID
GROUP BY POST.ID
ORDER BY POST.ID
```

Comment: Thanks! What you think is better and faster? A simple JOIN and I handle the multiple lines in PHP or GROUP_CONCAT? Thanks!

Comment: We might want to add a note that the maximum length of the string returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` is limited by the `group_concat_max_len` and `max_allowed_packet` variables. We might also want to note that `GROUP_CONCAT` is specific to MySQL. (But some other databases do provide similar functionaltiy, e.g. Oracle 11gR2 provides similar functionality with LISTAGG function.

Comment: Thanks @spencer7593 ... Each post can have 8 images. Each image name = 50 characters... 8x50 = 400 characters. That is very little.. Isn't it?

Comment: @guinatal: the default setting for `group_concat_max_len` is 1024 (I believe that is specified in bytes, not characters. If that length is exceeded, the returned string is truncated to that length, so it's a good idea to have a way to detect that the maximum length has been returned, that indicates that the returned value may have been truncated. Your use case may be a good "fit" for GROUP_CONCAT, but in the more general case (for the benefit of future readers), I think it's important that we be aware of the limit, so as not to be caught unawares (max name length > 128 chars, or #images > 24)

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables and you have what you want. You should simply order by post id and that's it

```
SELECT POST.ID AS POST_ID, P.COMMENT, IMAGES.IMAGE
FROM POST
JOIN IMAGES ON IMAGES.POST = POST.ID
ORDER BY POST.ID
```

Comment: This way, if I have 3 images, I have 3 lines... I would like 1 line per post... is it possible?

Comment: with an sql select you can have a result in form of a table. if you give me an example, of how the result should look like, I can tell you if it's possible.

Comment: You should be able to handle the three lines in PHP, that's why you should order the result by Post-ID

Comment: Yes yes... maybe I will do it... but I really wanna know the best way to do it...

Comment: OK, so you mean you should concatenate the images in one string, right?

Comment: What is better? What is faster? A simple JOIN and handle it in my PHP or concatenate? What is the best way?

Comment: Better and faster is a simple JOIN and handle it in PHP